# Вывод данных при GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Самая обычная база MySQL, содержит данные (отвеченные и не отвеченные вызовы):
Вариант 1.

```
calldate  |    src    | disposition
-----------------------------------
2017-07-17    747474     NO ANSWER
2017-07-17    747474       BUSY
2017-07-17    747474     NO ANSWER
2017-07-17    747474     ANSWERED
```

Вариант 2.

```
calldate  |    src    | disposition
-----------------------------------
2017-07-17    747474     NO ANSWER
2017-07-17    747474       BUSY
2017-07-17    747474     NO ANSWER
2017-07-17    747474     NO ANSWER
```

В первом варианте, звонок отвеченные, т.к. в disposition есть значение ANSWERED. 
Во втором варианте, звонок считается не отвеченным. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сгруппировать данные (по времени) таким образом чтобы, если среди значение в disposition есть ANSWERED,

```
 calldate  |    src    | disposition
-----------------------------------
2017-07-17    747474     ANSWERED
```

а если нет

```
calldate  |    src    | disposition
-----------------------------------
2017-07-17    747474     NO ANSWER
```

Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `select calldate,src,min(if(disposition='ANSWERED','ANSWERED','NO ANSWER')) from tab group by calldate,src`

Comment: Благодарю вас!)